# AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'CHANNEL'

Tags: discord, chatbot, discord.py

```
@CLIENT.event
async def on_message(message):
  if ":cmonBrug:" in message.content:
    await message.CHANNEL.send("Teste")
  await CLIENT.process_commands(message)
```

ERROR: File "main.py", line 33, in on_message
await message.CHANNEL.send("Teste")
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'CHANNEL'

Comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20channel#discord.Message.channel

the `message` object has a `channel` attribute, not `CHANNEL`

Comment: Wow. Such a dumb mistake. Thanks bro, it worked fine now